# Подключение к базе при использовании AJAX

Tags: php, sql, ajax, база-данных

Я загружаю страницу. Происходит подключение к базе данных для загрузки определенных данных (извиняюсь за тавтологию). Потом при нажатии кнопки происходит выполнение php скрипта в котором есть запрос к базе данных.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в последнем скрипте снова придется подключаться к базе данных?

Правильно ли так делать или нужно(можно) подключиться один раз и не повторяться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По коду конектиться надо каждый раз.

Но есть пара моментов:

1) Работал над приложением где после перезагрузки базы надо было перегружать `php-fpm`/`lighttpd` (`lighttpd`/`php5-fpm`/`pdo`/`postgres`). Т.е. Похоже конект или кэшировался, или не закрывался.

2) Сушествуют функции с постоятнным подключениям. http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php

Суть PHP в том, что **быстро** отработал и забыл. Поэтому на самом деле открывать на каждое обращение к серверу конект к базе, не проблема. Главное не открывать конект на каждый запрос который вы выполняете в скрипте. И что бы скрипт/запрос выполнялся быстро.

А если хочеться оптимизировать:

1. Оптимизируйте запросы (`explain` в помощ).
2. смотрите кэширование `memcahced`, `redis` ...

Comment: Спасибо, вот это по делу. Изучу

Answer (score -3):

Это вы забавно придумали.
Вы же подключаете php-файл с исполняемым кодом, а вот в нем уже и подключайтесь к базе. 
Отдельно конектится не нужно.

Comment: Видимо как-то я криво объяснил( Вот в этом подключаемом php обязательно ли конектиться?

Comment: Дык Вы сами и проверьте если не идет выборка и валит ошибкам то попробуй законектится.

Comment: Не идет, конектюсь - идет. Поэтому и вопрос задал "Правильно ли так делать или нужно(можно) подключиться один раз и не повторяться?"

Comment: да достаточно один раз.